# Проблема с работой функций sendto(), recfrom() через сокет дейтаграмм

Tags: c++, сетевое-программирование

у меня есть код клиента и сервера:

Клиент:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)


void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    char buf[100], b[100],b1[10];
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0)
    { 
        cout << "Ошибка загрузки библиотеки!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in add;
    add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    add.sin_port = htons(1024);
    add.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    int size;
    size = sizeof(add);
    bool exi_t = true;
    int ex, length, sen;
    while (exi_t)
    {
        cout << "Введите строку:" << endl;
        cin.getline(buf, 100,'\n');

        sen = sendto(s, buf, lstrlen(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &add, size);
        if (sen < 0)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка отправки данных" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }

        int rv = recvfrom(s, b, sizeof(b), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &add, &size);
        if (rv < 0)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка приема данных" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }
        b[rv] = '\0';
        cout << "Принятые данные: "<< b << endl;
        cout<<"Для выхода из программы нажмите 1, чтобы продолжить - 2: "<<endl;
        cin >> ex;
        if (ex == 1)
        {
            exi_t = false;
        }
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Сервер:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSAData wsaData;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1024);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

    bind(s, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    int size;
    size = sizeof(addr);
    int sen = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        char buf[100], buf1[100];
            int rv = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &size);
            if (rv < 0)
            {
                cout << "Ошибка приема данных" << endl;
                system("pause");
                exit(1);
            }
            buf[rv] = '\0';
            cout << "Количество прочитанных байт: " << rv << endl;
            cout << buf << endl;
            int k = 3, len = 0;
            while (buf[len] != '\0')
            {
                len++;
            }
            cout << "Длина строки: " << len << endl;
            if (len % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < len - 5; i++)
                {

                    buf1[i] = buf[k];
                    k++;

                }
                buf1[len - 5] = '\0';
                sen = sendto(s, buf1, lstrlen(buf1), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, size);
            }
            else
            {
                sen = sendto(s, buf, lstrlen(buf), 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, size);
            }

    }
    closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
}
```

Если установить соединение и 1 раз передать данные серверу, то все вроде норм. Но если в повторно войти в цикл, то выдает ошибку следующего вида:

[image: Вот скрин ошибки]

При этом в исходном файле сервера не указывается на какой строке ошибка. Ребят помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Откройте "стек вызовов" call stack (изучить меню IDE у всех современных есть) - там можно найти место вызова.

Comment: Поставлю на то, что, получив сто байт, вы пытаетесь установить buf[100] в 0x0, а массив имеет размер всего сто байт, а не 101.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за советы. Проблема была в следующем:
после ввода "2" для продолжения работы в цикле, в потоке остается '\n' и сin.getline() пропускает ввод и посылает буфер на 0 символов. Так как у меня не была предусмотрена проверка на минимальный ввод строки из 5 символов( по условию я передаю строку и если ее длинна четная, то я удаляю первых 3 и последних два символа этой строки и возвращаю ее обратно клиенту). Так вот: в сервере я считаю длину принятой строки и получаю соответственно 0. Потом я проверяю условие на четность и так как 0%2==0 удовлетворяет этому условию я начина в цикле убирать первые три и последние 2 символа, которых у меня нет(так как в строке 0 символов) и выхожу за пределы инициализированной памяти. Как то так. Если что не так сказал, то поправьте, пожалуйста, ведь я только учусь).